# How to make loot table not repeat items in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am looking to randomly generate 3 items using a loot table. The loot table currently works as expected, it will randomly generate an item based on the item's rarity. However, I don't want there to be duplicates of the same item. How can I set this up? This script is currently attached to 3 separate GameObject item pedestals.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShopItemSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class DropItem
    {
        public string name;
        public GameObject item;
        public int dropRarity;
    }

    public List<DropItem> ShopItemPool = new List<DropItem>();


    private void Start()
    {

        int itemWeight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < ShopItemPool.Count; i++)
        {
            itemWeight += ShopItemPool[i].dropRarity;
        }

        int randomValue = Random.Range(0, itemWeight);

        for (int j = 0; j < ShopItemPool.Count; j++)
        {
            if (randomValue <= ShopItemPool[j].dropRarity)
            {
                Instantiate(ShopItemPool[j].item, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                return;
            }
            randomValue -= ShopItemPool[j].dropRarity;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone the `ShopItemPool` list and with each item rolled you remove that item from the list. You then need to go all over again by recalculating the total weight.

I find it useful to have a general purpose class for randomizing items with weights, it allows you do this this:

```
var randomizer = new WeightRandomizer<DropItem>();

foreach (var shopItem in ShopItemPool) {
    randomizer.Add(shopItem, shopItem.dropRarity);
}

randomizer.Roll(); // Get a random element based on weight.
randomizer.Take(); // Get a random element based on weight and remove it from the randomizer.
```

#### General Purpose Weight Randomizer:

```
public class WeightRandomizer<T> {
    
    [Serializable]
    public class WeightedElement<T> {
        public T value;
        public int weight;

        public WeightedElement (T value, int weight) {
            this.value = value;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }
    
    private readonly List<WeightedElement<T>> elements = new();
    
    public void Add (T value, int weight) => elements.Add(new WeightedElement<T>(value, weight));
    public void AddRange (IEnumerable<WeightedElement<T>> weightedElements) => elements.AddRange(weightedElements);
    public int TotalWeight() => elements.Sum(x => x.weight);
    public T Roll() => Pick(false);
    public T Take() => Pick(true);
    
    private T Pick (bool remove) {
        if (elements.Count == 0) {
            Debug.LogWarning($"{nameof(WeightRandomizer<T>)} is missing elements.");
            return default(T);
        }

        var roll = Random.Range(0, TotalWeight());

        var selectedIndex = elements.Count - 1;
        var selected = elements[selectedIndex].value;

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];

            // Found an element with a low enough value.
            if (roll < element.weight) {
                selected = element.value;
                selectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }

            // Keep searching for an element with a lower value.
            roll -= element.weight;
        }

        // Sometimes we want to take and remove the element from the pool.
        if (remove) elements.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);

        return selected;
    }
}
```